# HTML5 Fit and Center Content of a Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to create a canvas that auto-fits and auto-centers the shapes drawn on it.

I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Fit Canvas Content</title>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
        Your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas.
    </canvas>
    <script>
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(-5, -50, 10, 100);
        ctx.fillRect(-50, -5, 100, 10);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please keep in mind that the canvas content is dynamic and that shapes can be at any location and can have any size.

[image: Collection of shapes ona canvas]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/e3qSP/1/

Here is the function used for drawing the plus with JSDoc included:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
drawPlus(20, c);

/**
 * Draws plus in the middle of the canvas with specified width
 *
 * @public
 * @param {number} plusWidth The width of the plus
 * @param {canvas} canvas The canvas on which the plus should be drawn
 */
function drawPlus(plusWidth, canvas) {
    var height = parseInt(canvas.height),
        width = parseInt(canvas.width),
        size = Math.min(height, width);
    ctx.fillRect((width - plusWidth) / 2, (height - size) / 2, plusWidth, size);
    ctx.fillRect((width - size) / 2, (height - plusWidth) / 2, size, plusWidth);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should of been more clear, but this is not what I'm trying to accomplish. I probably should of left out the example. I rephrased my question so it's more clear that I want this to work for a canvas with dynamic content.

What I try to do is more like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350413/google-maps-auto-fit-auto-center-autozoom-doesnt-work but than on a canvas

Comment: Maybe you're right and there's no easy way of doing this. Then I should indeed find the bounds of the canvas content to find a scaling factor. I hoped that there was some existing code/library capable of doing this.

Comment: I just cant understand the exact question. Can you show me what you want to accomplish and I'll think about more generic solution?

Comment: Yeah, I understand. You need scaling and translation. Here is more information http://goo.gl/ePolc, http://goo.gl/dZvtL

Answer (score 1):

This will fit and scale to the canvas.  Note that there is no padding, but thats easy to add

Firstly, you need to setup something to track transforms.

```
this.trackTransforms = function (ctx) {
    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'svg');
    var xform = svg.createSVGMatrix();
    ctx.getTransform = function () { return xform; };

    var savedTransforms = [];
    var save = ctx.save;

    ctx.save = function () {
        savedTransforms.push(xform.translate(0, 0));
        return save.call(ctx);
    };

    var restore = ctx.restore;
    ctx.restore = function () {
        xform = savedTransforms.pop();
        return restore.call(ctx);
    };

    var scale = ctx.scale;
    ctx.scale = function (sx, sy) {
        xform = xform.scaleNonUniform(sx, sy);
        return scale.call(ctx, sx, sy);
    };

    var rotate = ctx.rotate;
    ctx.rotate = function (radians) {
        xform = xform.rotate(radians * 180 / Math.PI);
        return rotate.call(ctx, radians);
    };

    var translate = ctx.translate;
    ctx.translate = function (dx, dy) {
        xform = xform.translate(dx, dy);
        return translate.call(ctx, dx, dy);
    };

    var transform = ctx.transform;
    ctx.transform = function (a, b, c, d, e, f) {
        var m2 = svg.createSVGMatrix();
        m2.a = a; m2.b = b; m2.c = c; m2.d = d; m2.e = e; m2.f = f;
        xform = xform.multiply(m2);
        return transform.call(ctx, a, b, c, d, e, f);
    };

    var setTransform = ctx.setTransform;
    ctx.setTransform = function (a, b, c, d, e, f) {
        xform.a = a;
        xform.b = b;
        xform.c = c;
        xform.d = d;
        xform.e = e;
        xform.f = f;
        return setTransform.call(ctx, a, b, c, d, e, f);
    };

    var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    ctx.transformedPoint = function (x, y) {
        pt.x = x; pt.y = y;
        return pt.matrixTransform(xform.inverse());
    }
}
```

Next you need to be able to actually fit the contents.  My function assumes you know the absolute width and height of the contents, you'll have to figure this out yourself but should be fairly easy. Note that if something starts at -150 and goes to +150, its width is 300.

```
this.fitToContents = function (widthOfContents, heightOfContents) {

    var p1 = this.context.transformedPoint(0, 0);
    var p2 = this.context.transformedPoint(this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    var centerX = (p2.x - p1.x) / 2;
    var centerY = (p2.y - p1.y) / 2;

    centerX -= widthOfContents / 2;
    centerY -= heightOfContents / 2;

    this.context.translate(centerX, centerY);

    var lastX = this.canvas.width / 2,
        lastY = this.canvas.height / 2;

    var scaleFactorX = this.canvas.width / widthOfContents;
    var scaleFactorY = this.canvas.height / heightOfContents;

    var scaleFactorToUse = Math.abs(scaleFactorX) < Math.abs(scaleFactorY) ? scaleFactorX : scaleFactorY;

    var pt = this.context.transformedPoint(lastX, lastY);
    this.context.translate(pt.x, pt.y);
    this.context.scale(scaleFactorToUse, scaleFactorToUse);
    this.context.translate(-pt.x, -pt.y);
}
```

Putting it together itll look something like this:

```
this.init = function (elementId) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(elementId);
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.trackTransforms(this.context);

    this.context.canvas.width = this.canvas.offsetWidth;
    this.context.canvas.height = this.canvas.offsetHeight;

    this.draw();
}

this.draw = function () {

    this.fitToContents(300,300);

    // you can now draw other stuff
    // you can probably only fit to contents once, 
    // in the init function, if their positions don't change
    this.drawStuff();
}
```