# Google Maps Auto Zoom and Auto Center

Tags: google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

Originally we entered the zoom and coordinates.  Now we would like it to auto zoom and auto center.  Tried `bounds.extend()` with `map.fitBounds(); map.panToBounds();` and can't seem to get it to zoom and center properly.  Original code below.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
var mapfunction = function() {

    $this = $("#map_canvas");
    $zoom_level = ($this.data("gmap-zoom") || 5);
    $data_lat = ($this.data("gmap-lat") || 29.895883);
    $data_lng = ($this.data("gmap-lng") || -80.650635);
    $xml_src = ($this.data("gmap-src") || "xml/gmap/pins.xml");


    nvisionhstyleMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(nightvision_highlight_style, {
        name: "Nightvision"
    });

    function xmlLoadMap() {

        var centerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng($data_lat, $data_lng),
        mapOptions = {
            zoom: $zoom_level,
            center: centerLatLng,
            //disableDefaultUI: true,
            //mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, 'nightvision_highlight_style'
                ]
            }
        },

        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        map.mapTypes.set('nightvision_highlight_style', nvisionhstyleMap);

        map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
    //    map.setMapTypeId('metro_style');

            $.get($xml_src, function(data) {

                // create the Bounds object
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                $(data).find("marker").each(function(){

                    var eachMarker = jQuery(this),
                        // grab the address from XML
                        theAddress = eachMarker.find("address").text(),
                        mygc = new google.maps.Geocoder(theAddress);

                        mygc.geocode({'address' : theAddress}, function(results, status) {

                            var mLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                Long = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),

                                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position : new google.maps.LatLng(mLat, Long),
                                map : map,
                                icon : ('img/' + eachMarker.find("icons").text() + '.png'),
                                scrollwheel : false,
                                streetViewControl : true,
                                title : eachMarker.find("name").text()
                        }),

                        link = "link";

                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {// click
                            // Setting the content of the InfoWindow
                            var contentString = '<div id="info-map" style="width:300px; height:85px; padding:0px;"><div>' + '<div style="display:inline-block; width:86px; verticle-align:top; float:left;"><img src=' + eachMarker.find("image").text() + ' class="thumbnail" style="width:80%; verticle-align:top;" /></div>' + '<div style="display:inline-block; width:200px; float:left;"><h4>' + eachMarker.find("name").text() + '</h4><b>' + eachMarker.find("address").text() + '</b><br/>' + '<p><a href="' + eachMarker.find("link").text() + '" class="btn btn-xs btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker"></i>More Info</a></p>' + '</div></div></div>';
                            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);

                            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
                                infowindow.close()
                                })
                            });

                        });// end geocode

                });// end find marker loop

        }); // end get data


    } // end xmlLoadMap

    // grey




    xmlLoadMap();

};


// end pagefunction

// run pagefunction on load

$(window).unbind('gMapsLoaded');
$(window).bind('gMapsLoaded', mapfunction);
window.loadGoogleMaps();
```

Here is what we tried with `bound.extend'.  It changes from the default value but centers it 0,0 instead of to the markers.

```
<script>
var mapfunction = function() {




    $this = $("#map_canvas");
    $zoom_level = ($this.data("gmap-zoom") || 5);
    $data_lat = ($this.data("gmap-lat") || 29.895883);
    $data_lng = ($this.data("gmap-lng") || -80.650635);
    $xml_src = ($this.data("gmap-src") || "xml/gmap/pins.xml");


    nvisionhstyleMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(nightvision_highlight_style, {
        name: "Nightvision"
    });

    function xmlLoadMap() {

        var centerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng($data_lat, $data_lng),
        mapOptions = {
            zoom: $zoom_level,
            center: centerLatLng,
            //disableDefaultUI: true,
            //mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, 'nightvision_highlight_style'
                ]
            }
        },

        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        map.mapTypes.set('nightvision_highlight_style', nvisionhstyleMap);

        map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
    //    map.setMapTypeId('metro_style');

            $.get($xml_src, function(data) {

                // create the Bounds object
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                $(data).find("marker").each(function(){

                    var eachMarker = jQuery(this),
                        // grab the address from XML
                        theAddress = eachMarker.find("address").text(),
                        mygc = new google.maps.Geocoder(theAddress);

                        mygc.geocode({'address' : theAddress}, function(results, status) {

                            var mLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                Long = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),

                                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position : new google.maps.LatLng(mLat, Long),
                                map : map,
                                icon : ('img/' + eachMarker.find("icons").text() + '.png'),
                                scrollwheel : false,
                                streetViewControl : true,
                                title : eachMarker.find("name").text()
                        }),

                        link = "link";
                        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(mLat, Long));  

                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {// click
                            // Setting the content of the InfoWindow
                            var contentString = '<div id="info-map" style="width:300px; height:85px; padding:0px;"><div>' + '<div style="display:inline-block; width:86px; verticle-align:top; float:left;"><img src=' + eachMarker.find("image").text() + ' class="thumbnail" style="width:80%; verticle-align:top;" /></div>' + '<div style="display:inline-block; width:200px; float:left;"><h4>' + eachMarker.find("name").text() + '</h4><b>' + eachMarker.find("address").text() + '</b><br/>' + '<p><a href="' + eachMarker.find("link").text() + '" class="btn btn-xs btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker"></i>More Info</a></p>' + '</div></div></div>';
                            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);

                            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
                                infowindow.close()
                                })
                            });

                        });// end geocode

                });// end find marker loop

        }); // end get data

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        map.panToBounds(bounds);
    } // end xmlLoadMap

    // grey

    xmlLoadMap();

};


// end pagefunction

// run pagefunction on load

$(window).unbind('gMapsLoaded');
$(window).bind('gMapsLoaded', mapfunction);
window.loadGoogleMaps();
```

Comment: please post your attempt to use bounds.extend and fitBounds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps auto-fit (auto center & autozoom) doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350413/google-maps-auto-fit-auto-center-autozoom-doesnt-work?rq=1)

Comment: Added attempt. Seems to not be pulling marker coordinates as it does rest and zoom but does so to (0,0).

Comment: Ran console.log on bounds and it is pulling coordinates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3 - fitBounds after multiple geocoder requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336405/google-maps-api-v3-fitbounds-after-multiple-geocoder-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Got it! `map.fitBounds()` needs to be called before Geocode end. Added `address_count++` to geocode and called `map.fitBounds()` on last marker.

```
                    if(address_count == $(data).find("marker").length) {    
                        map.fitBounds(bounds);
                        map.panToBounds(bounds); 
                    }
                });// end geocode

            });// end find marker loop

        }); // end get data

    } // end xmlLoadMap

   xmlLoadMap();
};
```

Comment: The general concept is the fitBounds needs to be called after all the points have been added to the bounds.  The geocoder is asynchronous and the callback function runs when the data is returned from the server.  The main requirement is it needs to run in the last callback function (but doing it every time means it will run the last time also).

Comment: Updated to call on last marker.  Thanks for your help!